# How to lazy initialize Collectors.toList() in java 8 stream api?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to collect items based on a filter. But the resulting list should not be initialized if no match was found. I'd prefer null instead of empty list.

```
List<String> match = list
            .stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getProperty == "match")
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

if (match != null && !match.isEmpty()) {
    //handle seldom match
}
```

Problem: most of the time I will *not* have a match, resulting in an empty collection. Which means most of the time the list is instanciated even though I don't need it.

Comment: Are multiple matches possible, or do you care only about the first match found? Perhaps you don't need to collect to a List.

Comment: what about `String match = list.stream()
        .filter(item -> "match".equalsIgnoreCase(item.getProperty()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);`

Comment: I care about all matches found. That's why I'm collecting to a list, and not using `.anyMatch()`.

Answer (score 5):

`Collecto.toList()` allocates a `List` using `ArrayList::new` which is a *very* cheap operation since `ArrayList` doesn't actually allocate the backing array until elements are inserted. All the constructor does is initialize an internal `Object[]` field to the value of a *statically created* empty array. The actual backing array is initialized to its "initial size" only when the first element is inserted.

So why go through the pain of avoiding this construction? It sounds like a premature optimization.

If you're so worried about GC pressure, just don't use Streams. The stream and the Collector itself are probably quite a lot more "expensive" to create than the list.

Comment: Doesn't `ArrayList::new` mean the constructor `new ArrayList()` which allocates an initial capacity of 10? [See the line 152](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) of the source code of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Nikolas look at the actual implementation. The capacity of 10 is not being allocated in the constructor. The backing array is allocated only when the first element is added.

Comment: @Nikolas afaik, this is an optimization introduced in Java 8, after the observation that it is very common to have empty `ArrayList` instances flying around.

Comment: @Holger From looking at OpenJDK's source for JDK6 & JDK7 it looks like you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I am only thinking of a case when something other than `Collectors.toList()` would be expensive to compute, otherwise use:

```
... collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(list -> {
          list.isEmpty() ? null: list;
   }))
```

But just keep in mind that someone using that `List` would most probably expect an empty one in case of missing elements, instead of a null.

Creating an empty `ArrayList` is quite cheap and laziness here would only make things worse.

Otherwise, here is a variant that could defer to null if you *really really* wanted to:

```
 private static <T> List<T> list(Stream<T> stream) {
    Spliterator<T> sp = stream.spliterator();
    if (sp.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Exact zero known");
        return null;
    }

    T[] first = (T[]) new Object[1];
    boolean b = sp.tryAdvance(x -> first[0] = x);
    if (b) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(first[0]);
        sp.forEachRemaining(list::add);
        return list;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: `estimateSize()` is named such because it is an *estimate*, not a precisely known size, so when `estimateSize() == 0`,it may still happen to have elements. Besides that, constructing a single-element array is not cheaper than constructing an empty `ArrayList`, so you’re making the non-empty case more expensive without improving the empty case…

Comment: @Holger agreed with the first, the second I thought I made it clear that it probably makes no sense to do in case of an `ArrayList` anyway. thx for the comment